# C# new class clears base class values

Tags: c#, class, parameters, field, radix

I've searched extensively (though might have missed it). I've been doing so much web development that I can't seem to get this. I have a base case:

```
public class myfields
{
    public String myfield1 { get; set; }
}
```

Then another class using this class:

```
class mydohere : myfields
{
    public Boolean getValue {string xyz)
    {
        string abc = myfield1;
    }
}
```

What I can't get it is, if I create:

```
mydohere Objmydohere  = new mydohere();
```

The value of myfield1 is now null! All the values in base myfields are set to null (or empty since it is a new object). What is the best way to create fields (or parameters) in one class and share it among others without resetting their values? I've tried using keyword 'base'. I've tried using props and fields *since you can't instantiate them).

My goal is to to have a class of settable fields that I can use accross classes without making that class new for each class that is using it. Does this make sense? I'm sure there is a much better way to do this :)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what you're looking for is a `constant` or `static` variable.

Use constant if it will always be the same:

```
const string myfield1 = "my const";
```

Use static if you'd like to set it once, maybe after doing some logic:

```
static string myfield1 = "my static";
```

Comment: The protection level didn't allow just 'static'. But this worked!public static String myfield1{ get; set; }, why is that? It used the value from the calling class (where it was set) and then allowed more fields to be set without affecting the calling classes set values. Thanx!

Answer (score 0):

This really depends on what you want to do with this "shared data" One way is to use a static class and dependency injection:

```
public interface Imyfields
{
    String myfield1 { get; set; }
}

public class myfields : Imyfields
{
    private static readonly Imyfields instance = new myfields();

    private myfields()
    {
    }

    public static Imyfields Instance
    {
        get
        {
            return instance;
        }
    }

    public String myfield1 { get; set; }
}

class mydohere
{
    private readonly Imyfields myfields;

    public mydohere(Imyfields myfields)
    {
        this.myfields = myfields;
    }

    public Boolean getValue(string xyz)
    {
        string abc = this.myfields.myfield1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is reset to null, it's never initialized with a value in the first time. In your base object, you only have a getter/setter, you don't have any code that initialize the value itself.

Maybe I don't understand the question well and others suggestion with static are what you really need! :)

Comment: that was my understanding too

Comment: You are correct. I do in a class (like a main class) set a few of the values in myfields. But then in main class I create a new class object and in that class want to set an unset value from myfields. (but as said myfields appears to be taken along for the new ride). I assume my main class that set some of those fields still has that object, and it does. I see a lot of good ideas and suggestions, I will try them shortly, thanx!